# Express $b$ as matrix multiple of $a$ given $a=(Mb)×c$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have an expression

$$a = (Mb)×c$$
where $M$ is an orthogonal 3x3 rotation matrix and $a$, $b$ and $c$ are 3-vectors.

I need to express $b$ as a matrix multiple of $a$. Are there any rules we could apply here to derive the expression? Or is it not possible?

Edit: Can we turn $c$ into a skew symmetric matrix $C^{*}$? And calculate $a = -C^{*}Mb$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is of course no solution at all unless $a$ and $c$ are orthogonal, so we’ll take that as understood. Unfortunately, you can’t recover a unique $b$ from this equation. In fact, if everything else in it is fixed, this is an equation of a line.

Consider the simple special case $e_3=b\times e_2$, where the $e_k$ are the standard basis vectors. Obviously, $e_1$ is a solution, but since $e_2\times e_2=0$, then $e_1+\lambda e_2$ also satisfies the equation for arbitrary $\lambda$. The situation is the same for the general equation: if $b$ satisfies $a=Mb\times c$, then so does $b+\lambda M^Tc$.

Not all is lost, though. The last expression above gives you a parameterization of the line if you can find any solution at all. Since $c$ and $a$ are orthogonal, we have by the “BAC-CAB identity” $(c\times a)\times c = \lVert c\rVert^2a$, so we can take $b=M^T{c\times a\over c\cdot c}$ as a particular solution, and the general solution is therefore $$M^T\left({c\times a\over c\cdot c} + \lambda c\right).$$

Your idea of rewriting the cross product as the matrix multiplication $-a=[c]_\times Mb$ is interesting. Unfortunately, the matrix $[c]_\times M$ is singular, so you again end up with an infinite number of solutions if there are any at all. Still, that’s a system of three linear equations in three unknowns, with only two independent equations, so you can use your favorite technique for solving it.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! My linear algebra skills are lacking, could I ask why $ [c]_{×}M$ would be singular?

Comment: @LennyWhite $[c]_\times$ is singular: $[c]_\times c=0$, so it has a nontrivial null space.

Answer (score 1):

If $a = (Mb) \times c$, we have $a \times a = ((Mb) \times c) \times a$, i.e. $0 = ((Mb) \times c) \times a$. By the [vector triple product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Vector_triple_product), this becomes $0 = (a \cdot (Mb))c - (a \cdot c)Mb$.

If $a \cdot c \neq 0$, it follows that \begin{equation*}Mb = \frac{a\cdot(Mb)}{a \cdot c}c\end{equation*} so \begin{equation*}b = \frac{a\cdot(Mb)}{a \cdot c}M^{-1}c\end{equation*} On the other hand, if $a \cdot c = 0$, then $(a\cdot(Mb))c = 0$, so $c = 0$ or $a \cdot (Mb) = 0$. In those cases, you cannot say anything about $b$.

Comment: We have b on both sides so this unfortunately doesn't work for me, but thanks anyway. Didn't know you could cross product both sides, that's neat. What about using skew symmetric matrix as I suggested in an edit, would that work?

Comment: I don't see, first of all, how you would turn $c$ into a skew-symmetric matrix: if you made $c$ a column or row of that matrix, then at least one of its components would have to be $0$, since in a skew-symmetric matrix, all the diagonal entries are $0$. Secondly, I don't see how you get to your suggested $a = -C^{*}Mb$.

Comment: $a\cdot c = 0$ always holds, since $a$ is a cross product with $c$ as a factor.

Comment: And why would having zeros along the main diagonal of the matrix that corresponds to $c$ be a problem?